# Does anyone know how to convert an ordinal to a cardinal number in PHP?

Tags: php, ordinals

I know there is a way to make a cardinal numeral into an ordinal. I can use [NumberFormmatter::format](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.format.php) for this. However, I would like to go the other direction.

Answer (score 0):

The current, (not very good solution in my opinion) is to do the following

```
function convertOrdinalToCardinal($word) {
  $ordinals = array();
  for ($i=1; $i<=100; $i++) {
    $ordinals[NumberFormatter::format($i, NumberFormatter::ORDINAL)] = $i;
  }
  return $ordinals[$word];
}
```